# What are disordered superconductors? What kind of research is done in this area?

Tags: condensed-matter, terminology, superconductivity

I was talking with a friend of mine and he mentioned that his professor does research on disordered superconductivity. I had a rough idea of what superconductivity is, but when I looked up the term ["disordered superconductors"](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=disordered+superconductor), all I found were links to research articles. I would like to know what this phenomena/technology is, for my own curiosity.

Comment: Disordered superconductors are, in the historical meaning, bulk superconductors made with alloys. They are usually of type II, and they vortex properties are of interest for many things. There are many many researches done using these devices, like the penetration of magnetic field in superconductors, the use of vortices to stock information or to generate exotic state of matter, or to study topological defects, the superposition of different nature of quantum phases by penetration/proximity with a superconductor, in which case the interface usually make the system dirty, ....

Comment: @FraSchelle Thank you for the explanation but I beg your pardon, could you elaborate on what bulk superconductors are?

Comment: Bulk system means infinite system. To distinguish the bulk states from the surface states for instance. Usually bulk system are supposed 3D materials.